# Callback function never calle using multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pool

I'm trying to multiprocess a processus but I have some trouble understanding why my workers doesn't apply the function `get_data`.

```
methods = ["followers", "friends"]

for author in authors:
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    is_present = session.execute("SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE node_id={1}".format("network", author.twitter_id))
    if not is_present:
        for method in methods:
            print(author.twitter_username)
            pool.apply_async(get_data, args=(method, author, session))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    else:
        print(author.twitter_username, "Already present in the database ")
```

And the function get data is just a print():

```
def get_data(tweepy_function, author, session):
    print(tweepy_function, authot.twitter_id, session)
```

When I run my programm I get:
the list of all my author display two times but not the print of `get_data`

What is the problem with those worker? Why they don't call get_data properly?

Comment: How are you running this program? Are you using an IDE like IDLE? Often they will have a "fake" stdout that goes to their emulated terminal, but child processes won't know about that and you won't be able to see their output.

Comment: I use pycharm but I don't think the problem come from the IDE I just reformat the function get_data it was working before